# Curly Braces not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, parentheses, curly-braces

See the image, basically if I go to enter shift+[ or shift+] aka { or } in eclipse

I expect the editor to update the .java source with a { or }.

Instead it seems to be indenting...

Now I'm using a standard macbook pro, with English any ideas why eclipse won't let me enter the curly brace. It worked about 2 weeks ago, did an update... using Mountain Lion... now it's not working.
[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that you can enter the braces in any other program, such as the word processor?

Comment: Yep, that's what's really bugging me, everything else works fine. It's only Eclipse. Xcode, sweet. TextEdit, fine. Netbeans, all good. Eclipse...no Curly Brace functionality...making programming in Java close to impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by the following preference.

Go to `Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing` and confirm that the `Automatically close -> Braces` option is selected like so :

[image]

For what it's worth, I have never had the problem you have been experiencing on Mountain Lion OSX and for the past few days I have been switching between Eclipse Indigo, Helios and Juno.

If the above does not work, try switching to a new workspace and try there ? I am not aware of any other preference which might be controlling this brace-closing behavior.

***Question*** : Which version of Eclipse are you on ?

Comment: I will see if I can't get a fresh install off the eclipse site and see if that helps. Unfortunately the braces tickbox is ticked. So the issue remains.

Comment: And a quick update. More bad news, I updated to the latest version of Eclipse Juno and the problem remains. Something must be up with the OS. Possibly a keyboard setting... but I have no real clue what the cause is right now. Frustrating!

Comment: It should not be something with the OS since I have the same setup. A new workspace did not work either ? Which version of Java are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Luna 4.4.2 and I could only get it fixed as pointed out by @Andriy .Seems like an internal Eclipse bug. The **{ Braces }** option only works if you select it and *Enter key adjusts the indentation on the new line* as well. Tested it here, so, got to check both.

Answer (score 4):

My solution was:

Help -> Key Assist then find skip Skip all Breakpoints.

Select it and press `ctrl + shift + L`. It will open a preferences window and then just delete binding.(`ctrl + alt + b`)

I hope it solved your problem!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Just delete the keys, simple. Hope it helps.

```
General->Keys->Type filter keys->skip  ->skip All Brakepoint->Bindings-> Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Eclipse Java EE for Web Developers Luna 4.4.1. Both of "Braces" options were selected. 
But **it started to work properly only after selecting "Enter key adjust the indentation on the new line**". 
Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, today I also got this problem on Eclipse Mars Java EE. It didn't work well when i tried to select, deselect braces options or any other solution from above, turns out while editing a code segment in few hundred lines above I closed a brace after the IDE closed it automatically. It's late for this question but leaving here for future reference to anyone who has the same problem

**Check your code for erroneous extra braces**